# Can someone explain why this code doesn't work? RE: string list manipulation with gross character length as criteria

Tags: python

**Objective**
Using a `loop` with `break` statement, take a string list `[headlines]` and create a string list `[news_ticker]`, wherein `[news_ticker]` contains (in order of precedence) the contents of `[headlines]` within a gross character limit of 140 characters; for the final iteration of `[headlines]` (i.e., the value with which its inclusion causes the gross length to meet or exceed 140 characters), if necessary, truncate the value so that the gross length does not exceed 140.

**Code Attempt**

```
headlines = ["Local Bear Eaten by Man",
"Legislature Announces New Laws",
"Peasant Discovers Violence Inherent in System",
"Cat Rescues Fireman Stuck in Tree",
"Brave Knight Runs Away",
"Papperbok Review: Totally Triffic"]
news_ticker = []
length = sum(len(chars) for chars in news_ticker)


for news in headlines:
    while length < 141:
        news_ticker.append(news)
    else:
        print(news_ticker)
        break
```

**Expected Results**

```
>>>
Local Bear Eaten by Man Legislature Announces New Laws Peasant Discovers Violence Inherent in System Cat Rescues Fireman Stuck in Tree Brave
>>>
```

**Actual Results**

```
>>>
>>>
```

Comment: I'm aware this does not contend with the truncation criteria, I've yet to cross that bridge.

Comment: When do you think `length` would change?

Comment: @jonrsharpe When `news_ticker` increments from `append()`, or at least that was my intention?

Comment: When you assign a variable, the value is computed and assigned. It does not create some kind of association that evaluates continuously. For that you need a function.

Comment: @tadman Well then, that was a big belly flop.

Comment: If you're used to mathematical functions, where `=` means "is always equivalent to" then there's lots of room for confusion. In most programming languages `=` means "evaluate and assign to variable" as you might write in a box on a paper form. There's no "equivalence" established.

Comment: I can explain why your [question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388112/620615) doesn’t work.

Comment: @user3840170 I was aware of it when I wrote it, but wasn't sure how best to word it without basically iterating the majority of the post objective within the question title.

Comment: @user3840170 Edited the title, is it adequate now or do you have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `length` doesn't change and values 0, you have an infinite loop here

```
while length < 141
```

You don't want a `while` as you don't want to repeat the append call, just use an if

```
news_ticker = []
length = sum(len(chars) for chars in news_ticker)

for news in headlines:
    if length < 141:
        news_ticker.append(news)
        length = sum(len(chars) for chars in news_ticker)
    else:
        break

print(" ".join(news_ticker))
```

---

But you can just concat all, and cut

```
print(" ".join(headlines)[:141])
```

---

To avoid `.join`

```
result = ''
for news in headlines:
    if len(result) < 141:
        result += news
    else:
        result = result[:140]
        break

print(result)
```

Comment: You've basically solved in 4 minutes what I've been quite literally balding over for the last several hours lol.  The only issues remaining: 1) the 140 character limit includes the white spaces (and headlines are joined with a single whitespace); 2) I'm not allowed to use .join().

Comment: @Arctiic I'm a python programmer for yearsn that's normal :D see my edit and the final solution

Comment: If Python were an Olympic event, I'd nominate you for the gold.

Comment: Just for completion and record retention, I've suggested an edit of adding ` + " "` to the end of line 4 and changing the result index to `[:139]`.  This outputted results that polled 140 characters in npp for me.  Thanks for the help!